# Removing an overlay on hover in using css

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a situation where a colour overlay disappears on hover. I have manged to replicate on in a fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/bzwogpkg/).

Css used on the site is

```
.rev_slider .custom-hover:before {
 content: "";
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 background: rgba(0,255,255, 0.5);
 transition: all .3s linear;
}


.rev_slider .custom-hover:hover::before {
background: none !important;
}
```

However, when i apply the same principle on a slider on my site, it doesn't work. The overlay appears but when i hover over it, it does not disappear. When selecting the the hover element in inspect element for the div, the overlay disappears. The effect is applied on the first slide of my site whose link can be found [here](http://goo.gl/a3utpy):

Help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's becose your mouse is not hovering over `.slotholder` element, but over this one:

```
<a style="width:100%;height:100%;display:block" target="_self" href="#">
```

I suggest you try to target that element, but before you'll have to organize your html output to fit the structure that you have in jsfiddle, that works ok!

Hope that helps.. cheers

Comment: Thanks changing the structure and adding the class custom-hover to `<a style="width:100%;height:100%;display:block" target="_self" href="#">' inside of slotholder did the trick.